# Ethernet adapter is blocking internet

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, macbook-pro

My MBP has an adapter for USB+Ethernet(single adapter for both). Whenever I am connecting it through USB-C port just to use USB (ethernet cable not connected), my WiFi internet is not working any more. If I disconnect it, everything goes back to normal. How can I still have Wifi internet, while above mentioned adapter is connected?

I've tried so far moving WiFi to top of the list in Service Order, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18458?locale=en_US

20second google

Comment: I tried moving WiFi to top of the list in Service Order, but it didn't help.

Comment: update will your question with all troubleshooting done :)

Comment: Could you edit your question to explain exactly what the Wi-Fi interface does or doesn't do when the USB-C adapter is plugged in? Does it stay connected at the 802.11 layer but IP traffic doesn't work? Or do you lose your 802.11 association? Try option-clicking on the Wi-Fi menu extra and noting all the extra info. See what it says with and without the USB-C adapter connected. While option-clicking the Wi-Fi Menu Extra, select the "wireless diagnostics" command that appears, and see if it tells you anything.